# Trying to Associate multiple route tables to the S3 VPC Endpoint ( Gateway ) using Terraform

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, vpc-endpoint

I can associate single route table to the AWS VPC Endpoint for S3.
But not able to associate multiple route tables with AWS VPC Endpoint for S3.

**Getting below error :

```
STDERR: \\nError: Invalid index\\n\\n  on aws_vpc_endpoints/locals.tf line 30, in locals:\\n  30:                                               route_table_name = rtb[idx]} ] if endp.service_name == \\"s3\\" ]])\\n\\nThis value does not have any indices.\\n"}**
```

## Terraform code :

```
variable "vpc_endpoints" {
  type = list(object({
     vpc_name = string
     vpc_cidr = list(string)

     service = list(object({
             service_name = string
             subnet_names = optional(list(string))
             route_table_names = optional (list(string))
     }))

  }))
}
```

Values of Variables :

```
VPC_Endpoints = [
{
vpc_name = TEST-VPC
vpc_cidr = ["X.X.X.X/X"]
service = [
service_name = s3,
route_table_names = ["Subnet1A", "Subnet1B"]
subnet_names = []
]   } ]
```

We are trying to get list of VPC Name, Subnet Name, Route Tables Names, Tags Name into a map using below locals endp_list and rtb_list.

```
data "aws_route_tables" "s3_list" {
  for_each = { for endp in local.rtb_list : "${endp.vpc_name}-${endp.service_name}" => endp if endp.service_name == "s3"}
    filter {
    name = "tag:Name"
    values = [each.value.route_table_name]
  }
}




locals{
  endp_list = flatten([ for vpc in var.vpc_endpoints : [ for endp in vpc.service: 
{ vpc_name = vpc.vpc_name, service_name = endp.service_name, 
  subnet_names = endp.subnet_names, 
  route_table_names = endp.route_table_names, 

}]])


  rtb_list = flatten([ for vpc in var.vpc_endpoints : 
  [ for endp in vpc.service: 
  [ for idx, rtb in endp.route_table_names: 
  { vpc_name = vpc.vpc_name, 
  service_name = endp.service_name, 
  route_table_name = rtb[idx]} ] if endp.service_name == "s3" ]])
}

resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "s3" {
  for_each     = { for endp in local.endp_list : "${endp.vpc_name}-${endp.service_name}" => endp if endp.service_name == "s3" }
  vpc_id       = data.aws_vpc.vpc[each.value.vpc_name].id
  service_name = data.aws_vpc_endpoint_service.s3.service_name

}


resource "aws_vpc_endpoint_route_table_association" "s3_endpoint1_private" {
for_each = { for idx, endp in local.rtb_list : idx => endp if endp.service_name == "s3" }
vpc_endpoint_id = aws_vpc_endpoint.s3["${each.value.vpc_name}-${each.value.service_name}"].id
route_table_id  = data.aws_route_table.s3_list[idx].id
}
```

Comment: You forgot to explain what's wrong with the code. Any errors? Also what are the actual values of `vpc_endpoints` variabile?

Comment: Hello Marcin, I have added the actual values of variables with the error message.

Comment: Its not possibile to even run your TF code. So how you could get such an error? Your `vpc_endpoints` says that `tags` is required, yet your `VPC_Endpoints` does not contain `tags` . Sadly your question lacks details and is unclear.

Comment: Provided the details and removed the tags.

Comment: Sorry, your variable value does not match its `type` that you defined, thus the question is not representative of your actual code and the error.

Comment: Hello @Marcin, I have edited the tfvars in the question. I tried it without the tags and add_security_group in variables.tf and getting the same error.

Comment: Hello @Marcin I have made the changes in the code, Please check.